# Wordpress: My Widgets bar display as whole page

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and I've encounter a different display of the Menu of Widgets. It display as 100% width of the screen I guess, I cannot drag my widgets to my site.

Please tell me how to fix these.

[image]

Comment: Does all page behave same? or only widgets?

Comment: Try to activate default wordpress theme and then check again.

Comment: please tell me how to do that, cause I can't find the set default theme. sorry for being so stupid.

Comment: Helping Hands --- it behaves the same like other menus. I think it is displayed like mobile view.

Comment: Go to Apperance->Theme , Activate any wordpress default theme , for ex : `Twenty fourteen`

Comment: I change it to twenty fourteen theme but the no effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96649/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-genesis-mallari).

Comment: It seems you don't use the default WP back office. Do you use any WP Back Office plugin, like Jetpack?

Comment: I haven't installed any plug-ins yet.

Comment: I just freshly uploaded it to webhost through Filezilla

Comment: Well it doesn't look like a default WP installation. Where did you downloaded this distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Super Thanks Guys specially [Helping Hands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4213132/helping-hands)

The FileZilla that I've used was the problem. I deleted some of the css codes I guess. I just used WinSCP instead and it work properly.

Thanks Again